# Find the sum of the following for any positive integer n where $\langle n \rangle$ denotes the integer nearest to $\sqrt{n}$

Tags: summation

Show that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2^{\langle n \rangle}+2^{-\langle n \rangle}}{2^n} = 3$$

I think I can do the following which I am not quite sure about:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2^{\langle n \rangle}+2^{-\langle n \rangle}}{2^n} =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^{n-\sqrt{n}}}+\dfrac{1}{2^{n+\sqrt{n}}}$$

But after this I am quite not sure how to form the two infinite GP series. Please help.

I have also learned that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{[x]} a^{\sqrt{n}} = \dfrac{2}{(\log_e{a})^2}+c$$ for $a>0$ and $\in \mathbb{N}$

Does this help my problem anyhow?
Snapshot of the original problem:

[image]

Comment: What does "the largest integer nearest to $\sqrt{n}$ mean? What is $\langle10 \rangle$? $3$ or $4$?

Comment: @RobertZ it has not been mentioned there. But let us consider 3.

Comment: You could use $\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust With $\langle n \rangle=\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor$ the sum is not $3$. I suspect that here $\langle n \rangle=\text{round}(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: @RobertZ: I agree. The OP wrongly phrased.

Comment: No  @Yves Daoust the question is not wrongly phrased. It is exactly the same written in the book Test Of Mathematics at the 10+2 Level by Indian Statistical Institute,Kolkata. I can put a snapshot of the same as well if you do not believe my words.

Comment: No @Robert Z the question is not wrongly phrased. It is exactly the same written in the book Test Of Mathematics at the 10+2 Level by Indian Statistical Institute,Kolkata. I can put a snapshot of the same as well if you do not believe my words.

Comment: @Saradamani: please do.

Comment: No I never do that. My own OPs are downvoted. Why on earth I would do that?

Comment: There are some "morally upright" users who do that. They closed one question of mine which I myself had to answer. They put it on hold first and then close it- very bad users they are!

Comment: Anyway, the text says "the integer nearest to"  Not the "largest integer". So it is the one I used in my answer.

Comment: Please edit your question with the correct definition of $\langle n \rangle$

Comment: Rather than complaining about users, you should try and understand what they mean and in what way they are helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. If $\langle n \rangle=\text{round}(\sqrt{n})$ ("round" is also called the [nearest integer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_integer_function)) then
$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{2^{\langle n \rangle}+2^{-\langle n \rangle}}{2^n}&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{2k}\frac{2^k+2^{-k}}{2^{k^2-k+j}}
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^k+2^{-k}}{2^{k^2-k}}(1-2^{-2k})
\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(2^{-(k-1)^2}-2^{-(k+1)^2}).\end{align}$$
Now, in order to obtain the final result $3$, note that the last sum is telescopic.

Comment: i have already accepted the answer by the way.

Comment: It is a marvel @Robert Z as to how you arrived at the second summation here. I can only look at it with awe and appreciate its marvel.